# problems in lucene android

Tags: android, lucene

I'm new to android and Lucene. 
I want to know whether I can use lucene for search in android list view.
I have tried importing the package 2.3.2 and also used the jar files in library.
However, there is an error in SearchFiles.java
error is :
The type java.rmi.Remote cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from .class files.

-Ketki

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lucene in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821103/lucene-in-android)

Comment: Yes, but the question is not answered there

Answer (score 1):

A user have [listed the steps to remove Lucene's RMI dependency:](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/601329551a87e601?pli=1)

> I just had to do two little modifications to the Lucene souce code:
>   1. Delete "extends java.rmi.Remote" from the Class "org.apache.lucene.search.Searchable"
>   2. Delete class "org.apache.lucene.search.RemoteSearchable"