# Is it possible to import Lucene Library in eclipse in android

Tags: android, lucene, elasticsearch

I want to implement elastic search in android with the help of Lucene Library in Android.

Can any one please guide me how can I implement this. And is it advisable to use or not?

How can I import this library in my Eclipse.

Comment: yep it is possible. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821103/lucene-in-android)

Comment: @blackbelt I read that post but no one has shared the code. Can you please help me with some code example.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't it anymore. It was a really old project. In my case I just stripped the `RMI` dependency and imported the jar, or use the v 3.x that has not the RMI dependency.

Comment: @blackbelt Can you please give me link to the library which to use and how can I import this library.

Comment: you can find the jar here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/downloads.html. Download the jar and put it inside libs. If you use eclipse you don't need to take any other actions

Comment: you could use this link for answer " http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4204 ";

Answer (score 1):

You could,  as the comments above show.  There might be some risk though,  [as Android doesn't necessarily implement all the Java API's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API).  SQLite has a [full-text search extension you could consider using.](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)  I would suggest SQLite,  or compiling any external Java libs as [Android libraries.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)