# Lucene Android NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lucene

I am developing a mobile application using Lucene. When I use `BooleanQuery` it works. But when I use `WildcardQuery` or `FuzzyQuery` I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at the runtime. I know android studio supports maven by default. I checked external libraries and all jars added.

My build.gradle file has these dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-core', version: '7.0.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-analyzers-common', version: '7.0.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-codecs', version: '7.0.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-queryparser', version: '7.0.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-queries', version: '7.0.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-sandbox', version: '7.0.1'
```

NoClassDefFound error:

```
Process: com.example.eren.lucene, PID: 7215
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/ClassValue;
       at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQuery.getTermsEnum(MultiTermQuery.java:300)
       at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper$1.rewrite(MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper.java:141)
       at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper$1.bulkScorer(MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper.java:193)
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:655)
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:462)
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:581)
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.searchAfter(IndexSearcher.java:439)
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:450)
       at com.example.eren.lucene.MainActivity.searchIngredient(MainActivity.java:262)
       at com.example.eren.lucene.MainActivity.searchProcess(MainActivity.java:216)
       at com.example.eren.lucene.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.ClassValue" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.eren.lucene-zYmMwtI9UFJUuvVsCJY1Gw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
       at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQuery.getTermsEnum(MultiTermQuery.java:300) 
       at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper$1.rewrite(MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper.java:141) 
       at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper$1.bulkScorer(MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper.java:193) 
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:655) 
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:462) 
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:581) 
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.searchAfter(IndexSearcher.java:439) 
       at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:450) 
       at com.example.eren.lucene.MainActivity.searchIngredient(MainActivity.java:262) 
       at com.example.eren.lucene.MainActivity.searchProcess(MainActivity.java:216) 
       at com.example.eren.lucene.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: did you first check if Lucene jars could be used on Android ( as is - out of the box ) ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I decided to implement a web server and run lucene on it. I think It is better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not fully support java8 features (See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support). The last release of Lucene on java 6 is 4.7. Compatibility of Lucene 4.7 with android is theoretically fine.

Answer (score 0):

This modification of Lucene 7.3.0 has fixed 'Missing java.lang.ClassValue class' error in Android 8.0 or above: https://github.com/texophen/lucene-android

See this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/76719236/22251021 ) for how to use it.